# import all files exported by client

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, node-modules

I'm making my own `restful-APIs` framework. Here is a simple overview of my framework and how it suppose to work.

```
/// backend


   export default abstract class RandomsRoute {
    
    public  async   get     (req: Request, res: Response):  Promise<void> {  res.send (`can't         resolve ${this.__getPath()}`)  }
    
    // returns caller file path
    public  __getPath ():   string  { return getCallerFileName () }

   }

/// client side
class MyRoute extends RandomsRoute {
    public async get(req: Request, res: Response): Promise <void> {
        res.send ('from client side')
    }    
}

export default new MyRoute ();
```

Users have to extend any class from build in the base class `RandomsRoute` and override some functions in this case `get`. `__getPath`   provide file path so I can create `express router` by using the file path like `Next Js`.

Under the hood, I'm looking for classes exported by the user. I cloud forces users to pass all exports to a function. for example:-

```
   import MyRoute from './MyRoute'
   .... so on
   import createRoute from 'mylib'

    createRoute (MyRoute,....)
```

but my target is to keep it simple.

`is there any way i can import all classes exported by users my own.`

**`Forexample:-`**   
`[Folder]route`    
  `- index.ts`   
  `- products.ts`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jordan check this question it may help you to understand my problem 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44004#discussioncomment-4394156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this package:-

[@randoms-pkg/code-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@randoms-pkg/code-generator)

### USAGE:-

- install package as a dev dependency

```
  ~ npm i @randoms-pkg/code-generator -D
  # or
  ~ yarn add @randoms-pkg/code-generator -D
```

- Add `randoms.config.json` file in the root of the project

```json
{
  "target":  "./src",
  "include":  "^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|\\[(?:\\.{3})?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])\\.js$",
  "outputDir": "./dist",
  "outputFile": "output.js",
  "preservedFiles": {
    "./_index.js":  ["getProps"],
    "./server/_server.js": ["getServerSideProps"]
  }
}
```

- Add CLI in scripts

```
 "scripts": {
   "dev": "randoms-generator"
 },
```

- test

```bash
  ~ npm run dev
  # or
  ~ yarn dev
```